# Geodjango, Openlayers 2: Override default fillColor in OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.style

Tags: openlayers-2, geodjango, vector-layer

*Update*

I would certainly [hard-code](https://github.com/openlayers/ol2/blob/75716beaacc01955f05708c03438b588fc8db55d/lib/OpenLayers/Feature/Vector.js#L437) the [source file](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/2.13.1/OpenLayers.js)
and change it as follows:

```
OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.style = {
    'default': {
        fillColor: "blue",
        ...
    },
    ...
```

... but this is rather a hack I would like to a avoid.

---

I am trying to change the fillcolor of a point shown in a django admin map.

I have already managed to change the color of a new point when I click on the map, [following this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12814897), but I am unable to understand how I could change the color of an existing point that programmatically is inserted into the map when fetched from the database.

I have found several posts that describe how to [override](http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/openlayers-users/2012-June/025308.html) the StyleMap of a vector layer or how to [dynamically style a map](http://www.codechewing.com/library/create-custom-feature-styles-using-dynamic-style-map-openlayers/), but I do not understand how I could change the color of the dot when it is already on the map.

I attach a picture. The yellow dot is already in the database.

How can I paint it blue?

Answer (score 2):

I have overriden the relevant settings as such:

```
OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.style.default.fillColor = 'blue';
OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.style.default.fillOpacity = 0.5;
OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.style.default.strokeWidth = 2;
OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.style.default.strokeColor = "red";
```